# Is this a perfect first question?

Tags: discussion

[How to use grounded European plug of coffee maker correctly in middle east countries?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/15900/how-to-use-grounded-european-plug-of-coffee-maker-correctly-in-middle-east-count)

I was impressed by the title, and the question itself.  It was clear from the title what he wanted and the body added the appropriate additional info

Answer (score 2):

Ill be honest. Its a good question. But not for DIY? more for electrical forums.

Even the answer is more common sense- buy an adapter. No DIY there either.

Great first question! Wrong forum?